# RewriteRule doesn't exclude existing files/directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So for a website I have an index.php file in my root directory that expects url parameters to determine which contents to echo:

```
example.com/?p=home
example.com/?p=blog
```

However, for aesthetical purposes, I wrote a RewriteRule in the .htaccess file in the root directory that redirect the following requests to the index.php in the root directory with URL parameters:

```
example.com/home → example.com/?p=home
example.com/blog/ → example.com/?p=blog
```

The rule looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# This is my rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(bootstrap|cms|php|pics|project|install)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC]

# The following rules are used by the CMS I'm using, so I don't want to change those
RewriteRule ^(cms)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(install)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)/$
RewriteRule (.*.html|.*.php|.*.htm)  cms_worker.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

However, using this all CSS and JS files that I included in the index.php using relative links (e.g. `<link href="/project/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`) aren't loaded as the rule seems to effect those requests as well.

Why is this happening? And how can I solve it? I thought the Rewrite Conditions above the rule should prevent the Rule from being applied when the requested directory or file exists ...  I tried adding the first RewriteCond to exclude requests to the specified directories from the Rule, but that didn't work as well.

**Edit:** It works fine if I access a page **without** the trailing slash (i.e. `example.com/blog`). However, when I access the page **with** the trailing slash (i.e. `example.com/blog/`), the CSS and JS files aren't being loaded. The network tab of the Chrome dev tools doesn't show anything, but when I open the source code and click on the relative link to the css file, it redirects to `example.com/blog/project/style.css` instead of `example.com/project/style.css`

Comment: Can you check your page in Chrome dev tool -> Network tab and see what css/js URLs are actually generating 404

Comment: I added some info! Hope this helps ..

Comment: 1. So the folder `blog` does not exist? But do the folders `pics`, `project` etc exist? Could you share the existing folder structure? 2. %{REQUEST_URI} is a variable that begins with a slash like `/index.html` what is not considered in the very first RewriteCond.

Comment: BTW, what's the cms? For the same reason (`%{REQUEST_URI}`), I cannot see the purpose of the last RewriteCond...

Comment: Sure. The folder "blog" does not exist. The subdirectories that do exist are the ones listed in the first RewriteCond. BTW I tried rewriting that cond with the trailing slash before the directory name, but that didn't wok as well. My CSS and JS files are in the project folder. 
I use [Dropkick CMS](https://www.yuzoolthemes.com/dropkickcms/). That last RewriteCond looked curious to me as well, but I didn't want to touch it as worst case, it would do nothing ..

Comment: @Zimmi I always use relative links so that I can, if need be, move the entire folder in a subdirectory without breaking the site. anubhavas suggestion (adding `<base href="/">` to the `<head>`) fixed the problem!
**Edit:** Also, using absolute paths is not an option for me as that doesn't work in my local development setup

Comment: Perfect, problem solved then !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is due to regex pattern used in your rules. Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# This is my rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(bootstrap|cms|php|pics|project|install)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# The following rules are used by the CMS I'm using, so I don't want to change those
RewriteRule ^cms($|/) - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^install($|/) - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.(?:html?|php))$ cms_worker.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

To resolve relative links add `<base href="/">` in `<head>` section of your HTML.

Comment: I just tried it, same results. example.com/blog works fine, example.com/blog/ doesn't load the CSS files :(

Comment: Then you're definitely using some relative links. Add `<base href="/">` in `<head>` section of your HTML.

Comment: Try my updated rule now. Esp. `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: I can't use the rule with the [L] flag as I need the latter rules to trigger for the cms to work. The cms works by redirection the requests to index.php to the cms_worker.php skript, which takes the original request as a url parameter, runs it and replaces keywords by some predefined content-blocks. The <base> element didn't work either

Comment: `L` doesn't stop rules below anyway. Even with `L` in that rule it will still execute `RewriteRule ^(.+?\.(?:html?|php))$ cms_worker.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]`

Comment: I thought the `L` flag stopped all other rules after that one? Edit: I tried your updated rule, still doesnt work :/

Comment: No `L` flag just forces `mod_rewrite` loop to run again. It was badly named as `L`, should have been `continue`

Comment: You have some serious issue here in your testing because **The network tab of the Chrome dev tools doesn't show anything** cannot be true. If it doesn't show any 404 then finding css/js is not an issue but issue could be in your js/css itself.

Comment: **It works!!** Finally ... sorry I didn't see anything in the network tab because I opened the dev tools after loading the page, I didn't know that. So I used your updated rules and set the base url to `/` (it didn't work before because I intelligently placed the `<base>` tag *after* the *<link>* tags .. now I feel stupid (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻
Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, maybe put the suggestion with the `<base href="/">` in your answer as well, as this seems to have been the actual solution